# How to find all nodes with greater or equal n labels?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find all nodes with greater or equal n labels (without knowing any label). Is there a simple way to do this using Cypher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With 3 as numberOfLabels
Match (n) where size(labels(n)) >= numberOfLabels
```